# Exporting cell array with both text and numbers to csv file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, printf, cell-array

I have a cell array with nine columns (the first eight text and the ninth numbers) and thousands of rows that I would like to export to a csv file.

I have tried to follow the suggestions provided in similar questions and I take that the best way to proceed is to use the `fprintf` function:

```
fid = fopen(outputfile, 'w')
fprint(fid, ???, variable{:,:})
fclose(fid)
```

Nevertheless, I cannot figure out what I am supposed to write in the middle. I have tried several combinations using `"%s"`, `"\n"`, `"\t"`, but it does not seem to work. Ideally, I would like to separate each column by either a `";"`, `","` or a tab, and to make sure that the decimals of the values are not lost.

Comment: The [documentation for `fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1) has an explicit section discussing writing data from a cell array. You need to expand on "does not seem to work," preferably with examples, before someone can help you.

Comment: `fprintf(fid, '%s,%s,...%d\n',variable(ii,1),variable(ii,2),..variable(ii,9));`, with `ii` as the iterator of a loop that goes from 1 to `size(variable,1)` could work.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your answers! @Divakar, that is what I was looking for. It helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.